# PersistenceException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: java, playframework, ebean

I have an issue in my code, this are working but is very
ugly and error prone, I am checking error conditions based
on the Exception message, so I need a recommendation to change
this.
I have an entity A and an entity B that have a B(identifier)
reference as "foreign key", so if found a B that reference
an A and I try to delete A the operation fail and launch
"PersistenceException".

NOTES:

1 - I am not interested in a delete in cascade.

2 - I am not interested in preconditions guarantees(checking that no found one B that reference A before delete A).

3 - My goal is try to remove A, if fail then process the Exception, but
replacing the `pe.toString().contains("...")` by an enum, error type or other option(if this is possible).

Thanks in advance, this is my code:

```
public static Result delete() {
        JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();        
        try {
            Long id = json.get("id").asLong();
            models.EntityA entity = models.EntityA.findByPropertie("id", id);
            models.EntityA.delete(entity);
            return ok();
        } catch(PersistenceException pe) {
            if (pe.toString().contains("Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails")) {
                appLogger.error(Messages.get("EntityA.delete.ForeignKeyConstraint"), pe);
                return internalServerError("ForeignKeyConstraint");   
            } else {
                appLogger.error(Messages.get("EntityA.delete.unexpectedError"), pe);
                return internalServerError("unexpectedError");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            .
            .
            .
        }
    }
```

Comment: and what persistence API are you using? because I see none there

Comment: I am using Ebean(http://ebean-orm.github.io/docs/introduction) that supports JPA annotations, not JPA2

Comment: I'd suggest you post to the ebean google group. This looks like an enhancement request to me.